# Usage of "a little bit" in "Can we postpone the interview a little bit?"

Tags: phrase-usage, spoken-english

> **Can we postpone the interview a little bit?**

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

I want to say, "I want the interview to be rescheduled to tomorrow at the same time," but I want to ask one question first, which is written above: "Can we postpone the interview a little bit?"

Is this correct?

Comment: *A little bit* is informal. I'd prefer say *Can we postpone the interview for a while?*. That's more formal, since you're talking about *interview*.

Comment: If you know how long you'd like to postpone for, then  I suggest you say it up front.  because you'll feel even more awkward when they come back with, "Yes, I can delay until 2:00 this afternoon" so that you are then faced with having to do a second round of negotiations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of the following sounds okay:

> Can we postpone the interview a little bit?
>   Can we postpone the interview a little?

If it's the day of your interview, I would interpret "a little bit" to be at most a few hours. If you wanted to delay until tomorrow, I'd just say:

> Can we postpone the interview until tomorrow?

Having said that, I would expect at least 24 hours notice if a candidate wanted to reschedule. I might agree to a delay, but I would view a last-minute request to reschedule as reflecting negatively on the candidate. The only exception would be a serious medical problem or other family emergency.

*Note: I work in a formal work environment. Other companies may be more understanding under a wider range of circumstances.*

Answer (score 1):

If the context is an interview, which is a formal situation, I recommend using ***a little***,

> Can we postpone the interview a little?

Comment: Is *a little* more formal than *a little bit*?  They seem about the same to me.

Comment: @snailboat At least to me personally. At least in formal meetings, I've never heard anyone use the word *a bit* before. I think it could possibly be different from one place to another. The use of *postpone* with *a little (bit)* is also rare in COCA (only 3 occurrences, all were *a little*). Google Ngram returned no results at all for *postpone a little bit*, but returned some *postpone a little*. The same goes to *interview a little bit* vs. *interview a little*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're 100% sure you're not in shape to do the interview, just contact the recruiter and tell them, "Due to unexpected family emergency, I need to reschedule, would that be possible?"

It may not be, and you may have to let this one go. But if it's not an immediate fill, but more of a general "cattle-call" they may be perfectly okay with rescheduling.

Comment: I'd say, "Due to *an* unexpected family emergency." I'd also be hesitant using this excuse unless it were really happening.